# Using IF, INDEX and MATCH to retrive the value out of the two column that is not blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

I want to use `IF`, `INDEX` and `MATCH` function together to get the output from the another sheet that has two columns (one of them in always blank and so need value from a column which in not blank).

The formula I'm using looks like :

```
=IF(ISBLANK('DATA 1'!B:B);
    INDEX('DATA 1'!B:B;MATCH(OUTPUT!B14;'DATA 1'!A:A;0));
    INDEX('DATA 1'!C:C;MATCH(OUTPUT!B14;'DATA 1'!A:A;0)) )
```

This formula is returning values from one column only and when the corresponding column is blank it shows `#N/A` .

I want it to show the value from whichever column (out of the two on another sheet) that is not blank.

Comment: I think you need a separator (`;` or `,`) between the two INDEX statements

Comment: I have it; I just missed it while pasting here... 
= IF(ISBLANK('DATA 1'!B:B);INDEX('DATA 1'!B:B;MATCH(OUTPUT!B14;'DATA 1'!A:A;0));INDEX('DATA 1'!C:C;MATCH(OUTPUT!B14;'DATA 1'!A:A;0)))

Comment: Can you post an example of what the columns look like? Do you know that all values you are trying to look up are present?

Comment: Hey ya thanks..!
 It is answered in the comment box. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(INDEX('DATA 1'!C:C,MATCH(OUTPUT!B27,'DATA 1'!A:A,0))),INDEX('DATA 1'!B:B,MATCH(OUTPUT!B27,'DATA 1'!A:A,0)),INDEX('DATA 1'!C:C,MATCH(OUTPUT!B27,'DATA 1'!A:A,0)))
```

though you need to be aware that `ISBLANK` will return `FALSE` when passed a null string (`""`), so if any of your entries in `'DATA 1'!B:B` or `'DATA 1'!C:C` contain such an entry (perhaps as a result of formulas in those cells), then the above will not give correct results.

As such, more rigorous is:

```
=IF(INDEX('DATA 1'!C:C,MATCH(OUTPUT!B27,'DATA 1'!A:A,0))="",INDEX('DATA 1'!B:B,MATCH(OUTPUT!B27,'DATA 1'!A:A,0)),INDEX('DATA 1'!C:C,MATCH(OUTPUT!B27,'DATA 1'!A:A,0)))
```

Assuming the returns are text, not numeric, you could also use the shorter:

```
=LOOKUP(REPT("z",255),INDEX('DATA 1'!B:C,MATCH(OUTPUT!B27,'DATA 1'!A:A,0),N(IF(1,{1,2}))))
```

though its brevity is arguably offset by its complexity and, again, this will fail if null strings are present in those ranges.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to mark it as the answer, in that case.